Function notation confusion: In "$f:A\to B$", is the whole $A$ the domain?

Suppose $f:A\to B$ is a function. Is the whole $A$ the domain or set of members of the domain?

In our book, it says $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{x+2}{2x-3}$. Obviously $\mathbb{R}$ isn't the domain here.
So what does the notation $f:A\to B$ exactly mean?

Setting "$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and $f(x)=(x+2)/(2x-3)$" is a mistake.

Oh, you are very observant!  You are correct. The domain is $\mathbb R \setminus{\frac 32}$ as $f$ is not defined at $x = \frac 32$.  So is the book wrong for saying $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  Well..... no.  except yes... well, maybe.  But no.... Okay. Some texts, heavy on real number practice, and light on abstract theory will assume all functions are real-value and mapping real numbers to real numbers and making such observations are minor... which really isn't fair on the student who will have it pounded in in other classes, to always state exact domain.

See also the post Function notation to relate Domain and Range

The problem here is that the notation $f:A \to B$ is overloaded.
In most contexts, it denotes a function $f$ with domain $A$ and codomain $B$. Such a function assigns each $x \in A$ to a unique $y \in B$. Therefore, for your example, we would need to write $f:\mathbb{R}_{\neq 3/2} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $f:x \mapsto \frac{x+2}{2x-3}$ instead because otherwise $f$ would not assign $\frac{3}{2} \in A=\mathbb{R}$ to some $f(\frac{3}{2}) \in B=\mathbb{R}$.
However, some authors may also use $f:A \to B$ to denote a partial function from a set $A$ to a set $B$. This effectively drops the requirement that every $x \in A$ must be assigned to some $y \in B$ but maintains that if any $x \in A$ is assigned to some $y \in B$, it is assigned uniquely (i.e. $f$ is a univalent binary relation from set A to set B). For any partial function $f:A \to B$, there exists a subset $D \subset A$ such that $f$ may be understood as a function with domain $D$. $D$ is called the natural domain or domain of definition. For example, $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $f:x \mapsto \frac{x+2}{2x-3}, x \neq \frac{3}{2}$ is a perfectly valid partial function since for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $f$ assigns $x$ to some $y \in \mathbb{R}$, it is assigned uniquely. Notice that it is ok that $f$ does not assign $x=\frac{3}{2}\in \mathbb{R}$ to some $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Instead, we can say the natural domain of the partial function $f$ is $D=\mathbb{R}_{\neq 3/2}$.
As mentioned on the Wikipedia for functions,

In several areas of mathematics the term "function" refers to partial functions rather than to ordinary functions. This is typically the case when functions may be specified in a way that makes difficult or even impossible to determine their domain.

